# Multi dimensional collection in oracle plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections

I have 3 tables `emp`, `dept` and `loc` and primary keys are `eid`, `deptid` and `locid` respectively. My requirement is to display `eid`, `deptid` and `locid` all together using Oracle PLSQL collection/record.

```sql
DECLARE
    TYPE COL_ID IS
        TABLE OF NUMBER(7) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
    X COL_ID;
    Y COL_ID;
    Z COL_ID;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        E.EMPNO,
        D.DEPTNO,
        L.LOCID
    BULK COLLECT
    INTO
        X,
        Y,
        Z
    FROM
        EMP  E,
        DEPT D,
        LOC  L
    WHERE
            E.DEPTNO = D.DEPTNO
        AND D.LOCID = L.LOCID;

    FOR I IN X.FIRST..X.LAST LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(X(I));
    END LOOP;

    FOR J IN Y.FIRST..Y.LAST LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Y(J));
    END LOOP;

    FOR K IN Z.FIRST..Z.LAST LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Z(K));
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I tried of doing this and it is giving me correct output but the display output is not in sequence and I know that this is not a correct approach to get this as there is quiet a lot performance issue. So can someone please help me modify the above program.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own type. Here's an example based on Scott's sample schema (so tables slightly differ from your data model and you'll have to adjust this code).

```
SQL> create or replace type t_row is object
  2    (ename varchar2(10),
  3     dname varchar2(10),
  4     loc   varchar2(10)
  5    );
  6  /

Type created.


SQL> create or replace type t_tab is table of t_row;
  2  /

Type created.
```

Sample data:

```
SQL> select ename from emp where deptno = 10;

ENAME
----------
CLARK
KING
MILLER
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_tab t_tab;
  3  begin
  4    select t_row(e.ename, d.dname, d.loc)
  5      bulk collect into l_tab
  6      from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
  7      where d.deptno = 10;
  8
  9    for i in 1 .. l_tab.count loop
 10      dbms_output.put_line(l_tab(i).dname ||' - '|| l_tab(i).loc ||' - '|| l_tab(i).ename);
 11    end loop;
 12  end;
 13  /
ACCOUNTING - NEW YORK - CLARK
ACCOUNTING - NEW YORK - KING
ACCOUNTING - NEW YORK - MILLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

> but the display output is not in sequence

All your collections will have the same number of elements; loop once and output the values for each loop iteration:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE empno_tab  IS TABLE OF EMP.EMPNO%TYPE;
  TYPE deptno_tab IS TABLE OF DEPT.DEPTNO%TYPE;
  TYPE locid_tab  IS TABLE OF LOC.LOCID%TYPE;
  empnos  empno_tab;
  deptnos deptno_tab;
  locids  locid_tab;
BEGIN
  SELECT E.EMPNO,
         D.DEPTNO,
         L.LOCID
  BULK COLLECT INTO
         empnos,
         deptnos,
         locids
  FROM   EMP  E
         INNER JOIN DEPT D
         ON (E.DEPTNO = D.DEPTNO)
         INNER JOIN LOC L
         ON (D.LOCID = L.LOCID)
  ORDER BY e.empno, d.deptno, l.locid;

  FOR i IN 1 .. empnos.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(empnos(i) || ', ' || deptnos(i) || ', ' || locids(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Or, using a record for the combination of columns:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE emp_dept_loc_rec IS RECORD(
    empno  EMP.EMPNO%TYPE,
    deptno DEPT.DEPTNO%TYPE,
    locid  LOC.LOCID%TYPE
  );
  TYPE emp_dept_loc_tab IS TABLE OF emp_dept_loc_rec;
  emp_dept_locs emp_dept_loc_tab;
BEGIN
  SELECT E.EMPNO,
         D.DEPTNO,
         L.LOCID
  BULK COLLECT INTO
         emp_dept_locs
  FROM   EMP  E
         INNER JOIN DEPT D
         ON (E.DEPTNO = D.DEPTNO)
         INNER JOIN LOC L
         ON (D.LOCID = L.LOCID)
  ORDER BY e.empno, d.deptno, l.locid;

  FOR i IN 1 .. emp_dept_locs.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(emp_dept_locs(i).empno || ', ' || emp_dept_locs(i).deptno || ', ' || emp_dept_locs(i).locid);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*Note: You can: use modern join syntax; do not need to use an associative array; directly use the column types in defining the collection types; and add an `ORDER BY` clause to the query to specify the order of the sequence.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE emp(empno, deptno) AS
  SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 2 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE dept(deptno, locid) AS
  SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE loc(locid) AS
  SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> ```
> 1, 1, 1
> 2, 1, 1
> 3, 2, 2
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rhCgoTeF)